# Cannot Knit to PDF using MikTex

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, miktex

I tried Knit to PDF on R Markdown and received the following error:

```
! Sorry, but C:\Users\annaw\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.

! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

!   C:\Users\annaw\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

! pdflatex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Problem-Set-1-Stat-1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Problem-Set-1-Stat-1.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

How do I resolve this? I believe it may involve my MikTex / Latex installation. Thank you!

Comment: No way to know without seeing your .tex file, but If you want a quick check on whether it's your file or your LaTeX installation, try uploading your .tex file to overleaf.com and seeing if it compiles there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.